# Encrypting data larger than the RSA key (modulus) size. Encryption of splitted data into chunks, seems not to be working. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Please, read this first:

- **I know that RSA wasn't designed for data blocks encryption. But it's still possible.**
- **I'm aware of security and performance penalties when encrypting data chunks with RSA.**
- **I'm not allowed to use hybrid encryption. So the following steps are unacceptable in my case:**

> 1. Generate random key for symmetric algorithm
> 2. Encrypt the data using symmetric algorithm and the random key
> 3. Encrypt the random key using your public key and store it in the encrypted form next (or before) the data.

---

But I must accomplish the given task *by all means*. ***Thanks for understanding***.

I greatly abstracted and simplified the example to make it clear about the problem I'm struggling with.

```
string data = "message 700-1300 letters long";
byte[] bytes = data.ToUtf8EncodedByteArray();

// I'm splitting utf8 encoded bytes into chunks of 32 bytes each.
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>> batches = bytes.ChunkBy(32);

LinkedList<byte[]> encryptedChunks = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
LinkedList<byte[]> decryptedChunks = new LinkedList<byte[]>();

using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
{
    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    _publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
    _privateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

    rsa.ImportParameters(_publicKey);

    byte[] encryptedBatch = null;
    foreach (IEnumerable<byte> batch in batches)
    {
        encryptedBatch = rsa.Encrypt(batch.ToArray(), true);
        encryptedChunks.AddLast(encryptedBatch);
    }
    // Then encryptedChunks.ToArray() will be send over the network


    // When encrypted bytes are received at another endpoint, they have to be decrypted.
    rsa.ImportParameters(_privateKey);
    byte[] decryptedBatch = null;
    foreach (byte[] chunk in encryptedChunks)
    {
        decryptedBatch = rsa.Decrypt(chunk, true);
        decryptedChunks.AddLast(chunk);
    }
}

// After decryption of each encrypted chunk of data, I project it back into an array of bytes.
byte[] decrypted = decryptedChunks.SelectMany(chunk => chunk).ToArray();

// When trying to display decoded bytes as a string (as it was initially), instead of original message I get hieroglyphs.
Console.Out.WriteLine($"Decrypted message: {decrypted.ToUtf8String()}");
```

---

Here are extension methods (that are used within my code), if needed:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TElement>> ChunkBy<TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> source, int chunkSize)
{
    return source
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToArray())
        .ToArray();
}

public static byte[] ToUtf8EncodedByteArray(this string source)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source.ToCharArray());
}

public static string ToUtf8String(this byte[] sourceBytes)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceBytes);
}
```

---

P.S. I also tried before encrypting the data (text), **encoding** it into **ASCII**, **instead** of **UTF8**. This didn't help as well.

**Any ideas?** (except switching to encryption with symmetric key. As I mentioned above, I'm not allowed to do it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've slightly modified (look for the changed-comments) your code, it works:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TElement>> ChunkBy<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source, int chunkSize)
{
    return source
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToArray())
        .ToArray();
}

public static byte[] ToUtf8EncodedByteArray(this string source)
{
    // Changed: instead of source.ToCharArray() use source directly
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
}

public static string ToUtf8String(this byte[] sourceBytes)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceBytes);
}


[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    // Changed: Generate some sample data...
    string data = string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat<string>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789<>!?", 100));
    byte[] bytes = data.ToUtf8EncodedByteArray();

    // I'm splitting utf8 encoded bytes into chunks of 32 bytes each.
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>> batches = bytes.ChunkBy(32);

    LinkedList<byte[]> encryptedChunks = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
    LinkedList<byte[]> decryptedChunks = new LinkedList<byte[]>();

    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
    {
        rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        var _publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
        var _privateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

        rsa.ImportParameters(_publicKey);

        byte[] encryptedBatch = null;
        foreach (IEnumerable<byte> batch in batches)
        {
            encryptedBatch = rsa.Encrypt(batch.ToArray(), true);
            encryptedChunks.AddLast(encryptedBatch);
        }

        rsa.ImportParameters(_privateKey);
        byte[] decryptedBatch = null;
        foreach (byte[] chunk in encryptedChunks)
        {
            decryptedBatch = rsa.Decrypt(chunk, true);
            // Changed (critical): instead of chunk (the encrypted data) use the decrypted data
            decryptedChunks.AddLast(decryptedBatch);
        }
    }

    // After decryption of each encrypted chunk of data, I project it back into an array of bytes.
    byte[] decrypted = decryptedChunks.SelectMany(chunk => chunk).ToArray();

    var data2 = decrypted.ToUtf8String();
    // Changed: Verify that input and output are the same
    var equals = data.Equals(data2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Inattention was the cause of the problem. I'm so happy that it's working.